# Fill ggplot by Dynamically Chosen Column(s)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dynamic, parameter-passing

I am creating a ggplot barplot as follows

```
fill_by <- "some_column"
g <- ggplot(plot_data,aes(x = xvals,y = yvals, fill = fill_by)) +
     geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Here, `fill_by` is a variable containing the name of the column I want to fill the bars by. Using `fill = fill_by` in the function fails to produce the desired result since there is no column called "fill_by". Wrapping `eval` around `fill_by` doesn't help, and using the method of

```
fill_by <- enquo(fill_by)
g <- ggplot(plot_data,aes(x = xvals,y = yvals, fill = !!fill_by)) +
     geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

mentioned [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes.html) doesn't work either.

Is there some way to specify the value of the fill parameter dynamically in this fashion? The ideal solution would accommodate multiple columns specified a la

```
fill_by = c("col 1", "col 2")
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `sym` should be used to switch from character to name.

https://edwinth.github.io/blog/dplyr-recipes/

```
library(dplyr)

fill_by <- "cyl"

fill_by <- sym(fill_by)
ggplot(mtcars %>% tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% head(3),
            aes(x = rowname,y = mpg, fill = !!fill_by)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

```
fill_by <- "qsec"
[same as above]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This is very helpful, thank you! Only issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how to satisfy the last part of the question (i.e. filling by multiple dynamically specified columns). I've tried `fill_by <- lapply(fill_by,sym)` but that throws an error. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this would mean. Do you want two charts to come out, one with each fill? Or do you want two values combined somehow?

Comment: More the latter. I'm used to data visualization tools like Microstrategy wherein users can drag an arbitrary collection of attributes into the "color by" field of a visualization and the software automatically colors by all possible tuples of those attributes present in the data. I assumed ggplot supports this behaviour but I'm guessing my assumption was off?

Comment: Can you please show an example? For instance, what would that look like for the `mtcars` data?